# Question on Equipartition at Reheating?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

Apologies in advance if this is a silly question.

I am fimiliar with the idea of Reheating in cosmology, as discussed briefly [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/106950/there-shall-be-reheating-and-other-inflation-related-questions).

I have been reading several papers which make the assumption of 'Equipartition at Reheating', however I have not come across a definition/ description of it.

So, in Reheating we say that at the end of inflation the Inflaton transfers it's energy to the Standard Model (SM) particles, or some as of yet unknown particles, through some coupling.

As regards the Equipartition then, is it making the assumption that all particles of all particle species have equal energy after the end of inflation?

For this to be the case, would not we need either the inflaton to couple directly to each SM particle species?

Alternatively, we need it to couple to some as of yet unknown particle, perhaps a WIMP, which would then in turn need to be having many interactions with the SM particles in order to 'equipartition' (can we use this as a verb?) the energy out between all particle species.

If this is the case, it seems like a big assumption to make.

That is of course, unless I am missing something, which is highly likely!

Comment: Equipartition is usually applied to the thermal energy. I imagine, then, that "equipartition at reheating" means that the average baryon temperature, $T_b$ is the same as the average photon temperature, $T_\gamma$, at the period of reheating. I'm not versed enough in cosmology to give a definitive answer, so I hope someone better versed than I comes along and confirms or corrects me.